# intent-filter not working

Tags: android

One of the activities in my app has an `intent-filter` with:

- Action - VIEW
- Categories - DEFAULT
- BROWSABLE

Data - scheme is 'myapp123'. I want to start this activity from another application using the Intent but I get `NoActivityFoundException`. Even if I type myapp123:// from the browser, it doesn't get called. Any help on resolving this issue will be appreciated.

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="TwitterStatus" android:label="TwitterStatus">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <DATA android:scheme="myapp123" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

actually I have this callback address for OAuth authentication to Twitter

```
mTwitterCallBack = "myapp123://twittercallback" ;
```

after authenticating by twitter the browser itself tries to search for this URI

for the purpose of testing, I have put a test option in one of the activities as follows

### Activity

```
Intent tstIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mTstURI)) ;  
// value of mTstURI entered at runtime - myapp123://twittercallback
try {
 startActivity(tstIntent) ;
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}   

// always catches the exception.
```

Comment: Can please post the XML fragment how you define the filter, and how you try calling it. (edit your original question)

Comment: hey are you trying to open  this activity from another application???:o first of all the other app don't have this activity registered! :|

Answer (score 0):

add the host

```
<data android:scheme="myapp123" host="twittercallback" />
```

and try again

Comment: I had this filter earlier, just removed it for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I can see is with your Activity class name "TwitterStatus":

```
<activity android:name="TwitterStatus" android:label="TwitterStatus">
```

It needs to be fully qualified, or it needs to be prefixed with a ".", e.g.

```
<activity android:name="com.yourdomain.TwitterStatus" android:label="TwitterStatus">
```

or

```
<activity android:name=".TwitterStatus" android:label="TwitterStatus">
```

[The Android docs for the  element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) explain this:

> android:name
>
> The name of the class that implements the activity, a subclass of
>   Activity. The attribute value should be a fully qualified class name (such as,
>   "com.example.project.ExtracurricularActivity").
>   However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period (for
>   example, ".ExtracurricularActivity"), it is appended to the package name
>   specified in the  element.
>
> There is no default. The name must be specified.